# Nebula GridTreeViewer - Is there a way to show the filter like FilteredTree in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, treeview, eclipse-rcp, nebula

I am using a Nebula `GridTreeViewer` for which I need to add filters like eclipse filters.
When we go to Window->Preferences, we get a filter on top of the left side tree which says 'type filter text'.

I tried the `TreeViewer` with the `FilteredTree` -

```
final FilteredTree filteredTree = new FilteredTree(parent, SWT.BORDER
                    | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION,
                    new MyPatternFilter(), true);
 TreeViewer treeViewer = filteredTree.getViewer();
```

The above code works fine for a `TreeViewer`.
Is there a similar way to attach such kind of a filter to a Nebula `GridTreeViewer`? 
If yes, please tell me. Would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create your own quick search adapter. Observe the code in `FilteredTree`.

I can't post my own adapter, since it's company property. Here are some hints.

Things you will need in your `MyQuickSearchAdapter`:

- `public QuickSearchAdapter(Composite parent)` constructor
- A `setViewer(StructuredViewer)` API that does `this.viewer = viewer` and `this.viewer.addFilter(viewerFilter)` (see below for `viewerFilter`)
- An abstract method `getLabelProvider()` to access a viewer's `LabelProvider` (in our case, `GridTreeViewer`)
- Creation methods for a `Text` field that will represent the quick search area.
- (Optional) Creation method for a label/button that clears the text when clicked (as in `FilteredTree`) - although this is overkill, in my opinion.
- `private MyViewerFilter extends ViewerFilter` nested class, that does the actual filtering. This will have a `String` instance field that holds the search text; this field will have a setter that will be called each time you type something in the filter box. Will look something like `viewerFilter.setSearchText(filterBox.getText());`. This nested class will also override the `select(Viewer, Object, Object)`, which will use the `getLabelProvider().getText(element)` to extract the text for a certain cell. Something like:

  ```
  // Automatically adds wildcard characters before and after search string:
  public static final String QSEARCH_REGEX_PATTERN = "(.*)%s(.*)"; //$NON-NLS-1$

  private class MyViewerFilter extends ViewerFilter 
  {
      // --------------------- <Instance Fields> -----------------------

      private String searchString;

      // --------------------- <Setters> -----------------------

      /**
       * @param 
       *      Text that goes inside the REGEX pattern
       */
      public void setSearchText(final String searchString) 
      {
          //this.searchString = "(.*)" + searchString.toLowerCase() + "(.*)";  //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
          this.searchString = String.format(QSEARCH_REGEX_PATTERN, searchString.toLowerCase());
      }

      // --------------------- <Overridden search method> -----------------------

      @Override
      public boolean select(final Viewer viewer, final Object parentElement, final Object element) 
      {
          if (StringUtils.isEmpty(searchString))
              return true;

          final String text = getLabelProvider().getText(element);

          if (StringUtils.isEmpty(text))
              return true;

          return text.toLowerCase().matches(searchString);
      }
  }
  ```

That's the hard part. After that, you just make a class called `MyFilteredGridTreeViewer`, and add the quick search adapter along side the grid viewer. Also remember to call `quickSearchAdapter.setViewer(gridViewer)`, and you're done!